# Where to add preventDefault() in this code block?

Tags: javascript, html

In this code I am trying to figure out where to add preventDefault()

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item');
    if (element) {
        element.forEach(function(el, key){
            el.addEventListener('click', function () {
                el.classList.toggle("active");
                element.forEach(function(ell, els){
                    if(key !== els) {
                        ell.classList.remove('active');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is I have tried element.preventDefault(), with el. and even ell. but no look.

This is the corresponding html

```
<ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">a</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">a</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">a</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is the problem that I am tagetting the 'li' and not the 'a' within the 'li' itself?

Comment: you could just add the event listener to the `ul` tag and check if `currentTarget` is an a tag and call preventDefault there.

Comment: The simplest solution given your code is not not use `<a>` tags - use `<span>` tags instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an event parameter where your click event triggers. And, use `preventDefault` there instead, since you want to stop clicking event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item');
    if (element) {
        element.forEach(function(el, key){
            el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                el.classList.toggle("active");
                element.forEach(function(ell, els){
                    if(key !== els) {
                        ell.classList.remove('active');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault` is a property of the event, not of the element itself. Not sure about your exact use case, but you can try something like the below.

(I.e. add a parameter to the onclick handler, called `e`, and call `e.preventDefault();`)

```
el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // <-- here

  el.classList.toggle("active");
  element.forEach(function(ell, els){
      if(key !== els) {
          ell.classList.remove('active');
      }
  });
});
```